# How to assert with a debug message in Go tests?

Tags: go

I want to do this:

```
test.FailNow("My Message")
```

but `test.T.FailNow` doesn't take a message. I am currently doing:

```
log.Println("Expected exception but got none")
test.FailNow()
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See: http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Fatal (and Fatalf)

The docs say: "Fatal is equivalent to Log() followed by FailNow()."

Comment: Thanks! I think that was a case of API blindness.